# Когда использовать scope.$apply();

Tags: angularjs, javascript

Чесно, не зря пишут, что это сложная тема для понимания. Я не понял, как и большинство. 
Где использовать вот эту штуку?

Пример:

```
.directive('clickable', function() {

return {
  restrict: "E",

  link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
    element.bind('click', function() {
 $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.user++;
      $scope.bar++;
  });
   console.log('1')

    });
  }
}

});
```

Без обертки `$scope.$apply()` пример работать не будет.

Не знаю, нашел такую заметку:

**Важно: любые события браузера вызываются вне области видимости AngularJS, поэтому внутри ваших обработчиков таких событий необходимо вызывать `$scope.$apply`.**

Comment: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html
Google helps

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Так, а что конкретно не понятно? Функции $apply/$digest запускают dirty-check, и если данные в $scope изменились, то обновляют view, вот и вся магия. Когда вы изменяете данные внутри angular, например, на ng-click, он сам вызывает метод $apply, если ваш код выполняется не через angular, то нужно запустить dirty-check руками. Вот очень приблизительные примеры:

**ng-click**

```
<button ng-click="counter++">counter</button>
```

внутри себя angular, заменил это конструкцию на:

```
jqLite('button').on('click', function (evt) {
       evt.preventDefault();

       $scope.counter++;
       $scope.$apply();
});
```

или

```
$timeout(function () { $scope.foo = "bar"; }, 100);

// эквивалентна
setTimeout(function () {
   $scope.foo = "bar";
   $scope.$apply();
}, 100);
```

Всё это очень примерно, но суть в том, что когда вы используете биндинг или методы angular, он за вас вызывает $apply/$digest, вот и всё, ничего сложного тут нет.

Comment: спасибо...можно попросить еще парочку примерчиков ?

Comment: Да там куда не плюнь, в конце будет `$scope.$apply()` :]

Comment: ок...Спасибо.Буду пихать если не будет обновления.