# При изменении данных в сервисе они не изменяются в представлении.?

Tags: angularjs

Раньше данные хранил в контроллере, и, если они не обновлялись сами - писал

```
    $scope.$apply ( function (results) {
              $scope.resers = results;
        });
```

Теперь перенёс код в сервис, но обновлённые данные не видны в представлении. "Внедрять" `$scope` сервис не хочет- ругается.

Что сделать, чтоб увидеть изменённые данные?

Comment: Я не так давно изучаю angular и если честно чувства двоякие, он ускоряет разработку в несколько раз, но его идеология желает лучшего. Но это к делу не относится и возможно, что статьи о нем пишут в большей степени переводчики, а не программисты. А что касается Вас, так с точки зрения "правильности", данные и не должны обновляться. В идеале сервис должен возвращать значение после обработки аргументов. И скопе не место в сервисе.

Comment: @TwoRS код сможете предоставить? Чтобы нагляднее было в чем дело.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае, хоть это и необязательно, $scope не надо использовать в сервисе. Обычно передают обратный вызов, который обрабатывается в контроллере. Т.е. `$scope.$apply()` вызывается в своей области видимости.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', 'fctry', function($scope, fctry) {
    var callBack = function(data) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.data = data;
        });
    }
    $scope.get = function() {
        fctry(callBack);
    };
}])

.factory('fctry', function() {
    return function(callBack) {
        superAsyncFunction.success(callBack);
    };
});
```

Материалы для полного погружения (кроме официальной документации):

- [Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory)
- [AngularJS and scope.$apply](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)
- [Когда использовать scope.$apply();](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/360113/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-scope-apply)