# AngularJS как отследить изменение модели в контроллере через watch

Tags: angularjs, codemirror

На сайте нужен блок `textarea` с подсветкой кода в динамическом режиме. Использую `CodeMirror` - он заменяет мой `textarea` по `id` на свою конструкцию тегов.
Но все изменения в этом новом блоке мне нужно отслеживать, `ng-model` прописанный в моем родном textarea не видит изменений в новой конструкции.
Вот  инициализация конструкции с помощью плагина CodeMirror

```
var etalon = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('etalon'), {

    });
```

Вот так можно проверить изменения в ней

```
    etalon.on('change',function(cMirror){
        $scope.etalon = cMirror.getValue();
        console.log('change');
    }); 
 //etalon.getValue(); - получаем значение из блока
  //etalon.setValue(data); - устанавливаем значение в блок
```

При изменении текста в конструкции я присваиваю своей модели etalon эти данные `$scope.etalon = cMirror.getValue();`
Потом мне нужно отследить изменения $scope.etalon и записывать их в json.
Но при таком изменении `$watch` не видит изменений если эти изменения происходят в контроллере

```
 $scope.$watch('etalon', function(_data) {
      alert('Changed etalon!')
    });
```

Почему так и как мне отследить эти изменения?
Вот пример. В примере специально указано изменения `newetalon через ng-model` и `еталон в контроллере`.При первом варианте $watch изменения видит.
[Пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/8e1LEqO5q0RMuW1dgaO3?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему не обновляется view?

Потому что ангуляр не знает, что что-то обновилось. Функции `$watch` выполняются только в процессе `digest` цикла. Так как при изменении объекта, `digest` цикл не запускается, `view` и не обновляется.

Решением может быть прямой вызов `$apply`, либо `$digest` и т.д.

```
etalon.on('change',function(cMirror){
    $scope.etalon = cMirror.getValue();
    $scope.$digest();
    console.log('change');
});
```

или

```
etalon.on('change',function(cMirror){
    $scope.$apply(function(){$scope.etalon = cMirror.getValue()});
    console.log('change');
});
```

**[Обновленный Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PI7GQ7ryAsC5UxnS2FFq?p=preview)**

Вообще говоря, не стоит использовать сторонние яваскрипт библиотеки работающие с DOM прямо в контроллере.

Лучше всего либо найти реализацию для angular, например, [UI.Codemirror directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror#uicodemirror-directive--)

Либо самому вынести код использующий стороннюю библиотеку в директиву.

Comment: Спасибо. Я присматривался уже до готового Codemirror для angular. но что-то не стартануло, попробую еще раз. Благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте `$scope.$apply();` в места, где модель изменяется в контроллере.
[Посмотрите вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/360113/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-scope-apply)